# Facebook - How to test apprequest?

Tags: facebook, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I'm making a facebook application that can send apprequest (invitation to use the application) and since I have troubles with it, I need to test it.

Even if the application is in sandbox mode, I can't send this requests to myself, wich make it very inconvenient if I have to ask someone else every time : did it work ?

Does anyone have a solution ?